# jquery switch html data from ajax post response behavior

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to switch html data from ajax post response.

```
var check = '<option value="">All</option>';
var urlpage = 'select.php';

$("select#s1").change(function(){

 var s1 = $("select#s1 option:selected").prop("value");

 if (s1 == "") 
 {
    do something
 } 
 else 
 {      
    $.post(urlpage, 
    { 
       s1:s1    
    }, 
    function(data)
    {
    switch (data) 
    {
        case check:
          //do something
          alert("equal : " + check + data);
        return false;

        default:
          //do something
          alert("unequal : " + check + data);
        return false;
     }
   });
}
```

alert response is always this:

```
unequal : <option value="">All</option><option value="">All</option>
```

In another project I have done such a thing without problems. This is pretty much the same. 
what could be the problem? thanks

Comment: use `switch($.trim(data)){ ...` and also change `return false;` in the switch statement to `break;`. Use a boolean variable to return the function result.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent - I realized that there was a html "\n". Now I solved it with trim. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

i think your r returning false in both cases
switch (data) 
    {
        case check:
          //do something
          alert("equal : " + check + data);
        return false;

```
    default:
      //do something
      alert("unequal : " + check + data);
    return false;
 }
```